# main page stucks while pdf is not loaded on new page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As the title said, I'm stuck on a problem with javascript and form submission.

My problem is, I have an html page, with a form (in a modal exactly but it does not matter here I think). When I submit the form what I need to do is

1. Open a new page which has to load a pdf of hundred pages (about 100 - 300).
2. Validate the form.

The problem is, during the validation, if the pdf is not loaded, the page where the form is, is stucked or very very slow. And once the pdf is loaded on the other page, the main page is ok. How do you explain this, and how can I do to avoid this problem ? Maybe validate the form first an then load the page ?

I'm not a javascript expert and a precise explanation on what is going on will be perfect. Thanks.

Here is a piece of code without the real links

```
<form id="myForm" action="someURL" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" value="someValue" name="someName">
<a class="button" id="myButton" href ="URL_OF_THE_PDF" target="_blank" >
```

the JS code :

```
$("#mybutton").on('click', function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myURLForm,
    data: form.serialize()
    });
});
```

I put some sample code, I tried different things but none of them works.

Comment: Your ID in the HTML should not have a hashtag.

Comment: Yes, thanks I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a real HTML button here, because you do not need the href.

```
<button id="myButton" type="button">
```

That could work:

The onClick function for the button opens an empty page in a new window.
Then it sends the ajax-request first.

When that is done, it loads the pdf file in the new window, which was opened short before.

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
   let myWindow = window.open(empty.html, '_blank');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURLForm,
        data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
          myWindow.localtion = URL_OF_THE_PDF;
    });
});
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

How big ist you pdf file with 100-300 pages?

I think the browser is very busy loading the pdf file, because 100-300 pages sounds very big.
So it yould be better doing the ajax request first and loading the pdf file after the ajax request has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try this ! Thans also for the hash it was a mistake when I wrote the question

Comment: I tried this, and which is not good is that now my action window.open is blocked by the browser (pop-up). But I have no loading problem anymore